# Quoting regular expressions in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to write a condition that would fit all the lines starting with a space/tab and the word Path

```
/sPath.* - simple regexp?
```

I found that in Bash 4.* it should look like:

```
if [[ $LINE =~ "[[:space:]]Path" ]]
```

But this condition for some reason does not work.

```
if [[ $LINE =~ [[:space:]] ]]
```

work fine,  and displays all lines with spaces/tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use:

```
[[ "$LINE" =~ [[:blank:]] ]]
```

1. Quote the variable `LINE`
2. Match with character class `[[:blank:]]` which is equivalent of space OR tab

Comment: Why is it better to quote the variable?

Comment: And if i match with string [[:blank:]]Path* where * - any symbols?

Comment: You can use: `[[ "$LINE" =~ [[:blank:]]"Path" ]]`

Comment: @choroba: It is because `$LINE` contains spaces at start

Comment: @anubhava: So what? `l='  a'; [[ $l =~ ^'  ' ]] && echo Matches`

Comment: @choroba: quoting may be useful because of field splitting (tokens), e.g. `[[ a␣␣␣b =~ "a␣␣␣b" ]]` (replace `␣` with a space).

Comment: Works without quotes: `line='a␣␣␣b'; [[ $line =~ 'a␣␣␣b' ]]`

Answer (score 2):

From [version 3.2 onwards](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), the pattern (i.e., the regular expression) must not be quoted in Bash:

> 1. New Features in Bash
>
> ...
>
> f.  Quoting the string argument to the [[ command's  =~ operator now
>   forces string matching, as with the other pattern-matching operators.

In other words, quoting is considered part of the regular expression itself (literal `"`).

Moreover, it would be better to quote the variable `$LINE`, to prevent errors should it be empty:

```
if [[ "$LINE" =~ [[:space:]] ]]
```

Comment: What errors can happen if $LINE is not quoted in `[[ ... ]]`?

Comment: And if i match with string [[:blank:]]Path* where * - any symbols?